# better way to refactor/ rewrite messy method that checks many params[:action]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, location, parameters

I have several methods inside my application_controller.rb because I need to be able to call them from anywhere in my app. Also I do lots of param checks to see if should allow/disallow the method.

Looking for constructive thoughts on this code:

- Any thoughts on refactoring the params part?
- Any thoughts on refactoring this perhaps move out of application_controller? ( make it a model method, but this cannot redirect to certain url/location)

**is_deleted method:**

```
  def is_deleted?
    if user_signed_in?
      if params[:action] != "reactivate" && 
         params[:action] != "destroy" && 
         params[:action] != "enable" && current_user.is_deleted == true
        redirect_to '/reactivate'
      end
    end
  end
```

**is_banned? method:**

```
      def is_banned?
        if user_signed_in?
          if current_user.present? && current_user.banned?
            sign_out current_user
            flash[:error] = "Your account has been suspended for continued misbehaviour"
            redirect_to login_path
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this to a model is a bad idea. Render/Redirect is the job of controllers.

This is a shorter version of your code

```
def is_deleted?
  if user_signed_in? && !["reactivate", "destroy", "enable"].include?(params[:action]) && current_user.is_deleted
    redirect_to '/reactivate'
  end
end

def is_banned?
  if user_signed_in? && current_user.banned?
    sign_out(current_user) and redirect_to(login_path, :notice => "blah blah")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you using the [ ] block with include seems a very neat rewrite, your right on redirecting is task for controller